# How to use installed SSL certificate to secure iOS app?

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to secure a iOS app by checking the installed SSL certificate exists or not. First I created a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL, and then install it to my iPhone. Right now I need to programmatically check this certificate is installed or not. If it exists, the app can run without limit, if not, use won't be able to use the app. So how to programmatically check this device is installed or not in my app code?

Why do we need to install SSL certificate on our iOS devices?

Comment: You want to handshake SSL with the server or need to check valid certificate on local?

Comment: @CodeChanger I need to check valid certificate on local iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

> Users can install digital identities (certificates plus their
>   associated private keys) onto their iOS devices by downloading them
>   from within Safari, by opening them as email attachments, and by
>   installing them with configuration profiles. Or, identities can be
>   pushed from a Mobile Device Management (MDM) server. However,
>   identities installed in any of these ways are added to the Apple
>   keychain access group.

Refer below links for more info.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52345
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html

Comment: We can also add certificate in Our bundle and pin it...so that every time we can initiate SSL handshake...

Comment: @iAnurag agreed, this approach is more popular.